# How can I see two objects' keyframes at the same time on the dope sheet/action editor?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

I want to be able to see and modify the keyframes of just two objects at the same time in the timeline/dope sheet. When I select the action editor, it sends me to the single object.

In the dope sheet it shows me everything, but I only need those two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can limit the displayed channels in *Dopesheet* to selected object, by selecting the little arrow icon:

[image]

Comment: Wow, i didn't knew about that...thank you so much! :)